Relation between spontaneous emission and natural linewidth
I have a question regarding the relation between the spontaneous emission and the corresponding natural linewidth of a two-level system. The way that I have seen people deriving the lineshape from the upper state life time uses a classical description: that $p_1, p_2$ are the probability of the system in the ground and excited state. Without external drive field, the probability in the excited state exponentially decreases: $dp_2/dt=-p_2/\tau$, and $p_2(t)\propto e^{-t/\tau}$, with $\tau$ being the upper state life time. Then, the spontaneous emission field should satisfy $E_{sp}(t)\propto H(t)e^{-t/(2\tau)-i\omega_0 t}$, with $\omega_0$ as the frequency of the two-level transition and $H(t)$ is the Heaviside step function. Then, performing a Fourier transform of the field $E_{sp}(t)$, we obtain a Lorentzian line shape function:
\begin{equation}
|\tilde{E}_{sp}(\omega)|^2\propto\frac{1}{(\omega-\omega_0)^2+(\frac{1}{2\tau})^2}.
\end{equation}
This is only half of the story, since the calculation of the life time $\tau$ requires a quantum treatment of the electromagnetic field. The way that I have seen for deriving this life time uses the Fermi's golden rule. Essentially, we can calculate the rate of the transition from the state of an excited atom in vacuum to the continuum of states that has the atom in the ground state and one of the electromagnetic mode in the excited state. However, I do not see how this approach can directly lead to the Lorentzian line shape without resorting to the classical argument. Moreover, in the first-order perturbation theory that is used to derive Fermi's Golden rule, from the initial state i, the probability of the system in one specific final state f is determined by:
\begin{equation}
|a_f(t)|^2=\frac{|V_{fi}|^2}{\hbar^2} \frac{\sin^2{\frac{(\omega_f-\omega_i)t}{2}}}{(\frac{\omega_f-\omega_i}{2})^2},
\end{equation}
where $V_{fi}$ is the matrix element of the interacting Hamiltonian of between the initial and final state. From the standard treatment of Fermi's Golden rule, we argue that as $t$ is larger, only the final states that conserve energy are allowed. However, does this mean that if we increase the observation time, the spectral linewidth of the spontaneously emitted photon is going to be smaller? This seems to make no sense. Thus, the question I want to ask is that is there a formalism that can derive both the upper state life time and the Lorentzian line shape?
